# convert List of List to Java collection of collection in Scala

Tags: java, list, scala, collections, casting

Let say I have a List of List of an Object:

```
val myList: List[List[MyObject]] = List(List(o1, o2, o3))
```

I would like to convert `myList` to either  `ju.ArrayList[ju.ArrayList[MyObject]]` or `ju.Collection[ju.Collection[MyObject]]`

I need it as a java collection for parametrized tests

Answer (score 0):

Got what I wanted using:

```
testInput.map({itemList => itemList.asJava}).asJava
```